# NPM EXPRESS module installation error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting below error while trying to install EXPRESS.js package with NPM. I am not sure why this is coming. I am trying with admin user on Windows PC.

**ERROR 1:**

```
C:\Users\Dell>npm install -g express
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNR
EFUSED
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\npm-debug.log
```

**ERROR 2:** after running "`npm config delete proxy`" command.

```
C:\Users\Dell>npm install -g express
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.13.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND r
egistry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7968-a914624e\registry.npmjs.org\express\-\express-4.13.1.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: f117aa1d1f6bedbc8de5b6d71fc31a5acd0f63df
npm ERR! Actual:   6e848d49c41d8af4d604e4c76036af8a5552ec5a
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.13.1.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\npm-debug.log
```